# Syntax with where in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have the following simple definition.

```
f :: Int -> Int
f x = bla + blub
  where blub = 1
        bla = 1
```

The compiler gives me the error `test.hs:4:21: parse error on input '='`
I know about the indention rules, but all seems to be well indented here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's [absolutely nothing](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/597dd6f679d6e1bc) wrong with your code.

Comment: In my editor I inserted indention as tabs (not converted to spaces). If I use spaces instead it works. Thanks!